# Android Java: Get Open WiFi-Networks

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app that is automatically connecting to Open Networks (so no password). I know you can scan with `wifi.startScan()` and `wifi.getScanResults`. But how can I save all these Network Names?

So I can connect to them with:

```
String networkSSID = "test";
String networkPass = "pass";

WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
```

Sorry, I'm really a nooby.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you just want to store the strings for the SSID and keys so that you can easily restore and connect later?

The easiest way is to use SharedPreferences to store any data.
Here is a a tutorial by slidenerd that is very easy to follow.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riyMQiHY3V4

I'm a noob too, so whenever I have questions, I head straight to slidenerd or thenewboston on youtube and then start digging through tech documentation once I have a basic understanding.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I just want to get the SSID of Networks in my near without password

Answer (score 0):

## Filter out the Open networks.

Use this method to check if a network is open or not

```
private boolean isProtectedNetwork(String capability){

   return (capability.contains("WPA") || 
           capability.contains("WEP") || 
           capability.contains("WPS")
          );
}
```

Then iterate through all the network lists and get the all open networks.

```
private void getAllOpenNetworks(List<ScanResult> allNetworks){

   List<ScanResult>openNetworks  = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();

   for(ScanResult network : allNetworks){

       if(!isProtectedNetwork(network.capabilities)){
           openNetworks.add(network);
       }
   }

}
```

## Useful Resource:

You can find more related solutions on [My Github Repository](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Bulucu)